# Is there a dictionary that contains the function's parameters in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to get a dictionary of all the parameters passed to a function.

```
def myfunc( param1, param2, param3 ):
    print 'Param1=%(param1)s, Param2=%(param2)s Param3=%(param3)' % __method_param_dict__
```

So my question is does the dictionary **method_param_dict** exist, and if so what is it called.

Thanks

Comment: why do you need it? what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ummm... It's in the source.  What's the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution for your specific example:

```
def myfunc(param1, param2, param3):
    dict_param = locals()
```

But be sure to have a look at [this article](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/07/python-aggregating-function-arguments.html) for a complete explanation of the possiblities (args, kwargs, mixed etc...)

Comment: +1 as the specific example's argument positioning may have been important, and everyone forgets locals().

Comment: Thanks Jed - I've been staring at my Python Cookbook and Google to find that answer!

I was aware of *args and *kwargs, but I don't want a variable arg list, just a shorthand to stop me having to type the args all over again.

Comment: Oops - the thanks should have been to ChristopheD - apologies and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do that, you should use `*args` and `**kwargs`.

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   print args
   print kwargs

foo(1,2,3,four=4,five=5)
# prints [1,2,3] and {'four':4, 'five':5}
```

Using `locals()` is also a possibility and will allow you to iterate through the names of position arguments, but you must remember to access it before defining any new names in the scope, and you should be aware that it will include `self` for methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
  # Now "args" is a list containing the parameters passed
  print args[0], args[1], args[2]

  # And "kwargs" is a dictionary mapping the parameter names passed to their values
  for key, value in kwargs.items():
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept variable parameters, you can use `*args` and `**kwargs`.

`*args` is a list of all non-keyword parameters. `**kwargs` is a dictionary of all keyword parameters. So:

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
       print args
    if kwargs:
       print kwargs


>>> myfunc('hello', 'goodbye')
('hello', 'goodbye')

>>> myfunc(param1='hello', param2='goodbye')
{'param1': 'param2', 'param2': 'goodbye'}
```